# Programa em C fechando sem explicação

Tags: c, funções, arquivo

Estou fazendo um programa em C que tem como objetivo ler uma lista de compras armazenadas em um arquivo de texto e somar o valor total dos preços dos produtos. Em cada linha do arquivo tem, o nome do produto, a quantidade disponível e o preço unitário. Fiz todo o código e compilei, porém o programa fecha inesperadamente toda vez que ele chega na parte do código que faz a leitura e armazena em vetores. Segue o código:

```c
void main() {
   char arqnome[30];

   printf("\nDigite o nome da lista de compras\n");
   scanf("%s", arqnome);
   FILE *arq = fopen(arqnome, "r");

   if (arq == NULL) { printf("\nErro ao abrir o arquivo\n"); exit(1); }

   int linhas = 0;
   int letras = 0;
   char c;

   while (!feof(arq))
   {
       c = fgetc(arq);

       if (isdigit(c) == 0 && c != '\n' && c!= ' ') { letras++; }
           else
           {
               if (c == '\n') { linhas++; }
           }
       printf("\n%d letras", letras);
       printf("\n%d linhas", linhas);
   }

   char **nomeproduto = malloc(linhas * sizeof(char));
   for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++) {
       nomeproduto[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 10);
   }

   int *quantida = (int*)malloc(linhas * sizeof(int));
   int *preco = (int*)malloc(linhas * sizeof(int));

   for (int clean = 0; clean < linhas; clean++) { quantida[clean] = 0; preco[clean] = 0; }

   fclose(arq);
   FILE *arq1 = fopen(arqnome, "r");

   //int i = 0;
   int j = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < linhas; i++)
       {
           fscanf(arq1, "%s", *(nomeproduto+j));

           fscanf(arq1, "%d", quantida[j]);

           fscanf(arq1, "%d", preco[j]);   

           j++;
       }

   int total = 0;
   for (int k = 0; k < linhas; k++) {
       total = total + preco[k];
   }

   printf("\nA soma dos preocos dos produtos eh %d", total);
   printf("\n");
   fclose(arq1);
   system("pause");
}
```

Comment: `system("pause")` ? Qual lógica você quer usar isso?

Comment: system("pause") é apenas para o cmd não fechar imediatamente após a execução do programa ter finalizado. É usado no windows, já que no linux o terminal não fecha após a execução.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta 

Comment: Você está a fazer os `fscanf` errado. Eles devem ficar assim: `fscanf(arq1, "%s", nomeproduto[j]);fscanf(arq1, "%d", &quantida[j]);fscanf(arq1, "%d", &preco[j]);`

Comment: @Isac Cara... Muito obrigado, eu fiquei um tempao quebrando a cabeça tentando fazer funcionar, e o erro era tão simples, me deu vontade de me bater kkkkkkk Fazer o que né kkkk sou iniciante no mundo da programação e é apanhando que se aprende.

Comment: @Isac publique sua resposta. Para ganha reputação.

Comment: @Matheus10772 é inútil usar i `int j` sendo que no for tem `int i`

Comment: Use assim: `for (int j = 0; j < linhas; j++)
       {
           fscanf(arq1, "%s", nomeproduto[j]);

           fscanf(arq1, "%d", quantida[j]);

           fscanf(arq1, "%d", preco[j]);   

       }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo @isac

> Você está a fazer os fscanf errado. Eles devem ficar assim:
>
> ```
>  fscanf(arq1, "%s", nomeproduto[j]);
>  fscanf(arq1, "%d", &quantida[j]);
>  fscanf(arq1, "%d", &preco[j]);
> ```